# Ensure observable execution even without subscribers

Tags: rx-java2

I have a cache of observables and reuse them. They normally all use some sort of caching (mostly `replay(1).refCount()`) and I make sure, that the underlying calculation is done once only with this.

I now have cases, where the underlying stream emits items and noone is subscribed to my cached observable. I still want it to process this event. How can I do this?

Currently I only can do this like following:

```
val o = observable.reply(1)
o.connect() // make sure this hot observable always is connected and processes it's input
return o // this one is cached
```

Is there some better way? I want that the hot observable always acts as if someone is subscribed and never unsubscribes from the upstream...

*Background*

I have redux store like observables and those need to process EVERY input, no matter if someone is subscribed or not so that the cached values that a replayed are always the newest one...

Comment: I am new to RxJava myself, but does this seem like something that could work? http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html, subscribe to upstream to call on next of the behavior subject. That will emit the latest value to its subscribers

Comment: See [autoConnect](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#autoConnect-int-)

Comment: So `replay(1).autoConnect(0)` should solve this and I get an observable that will never unsubscribe from its upstream and that will immediately survive to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO the correct answer is by @prom85 in the question comment section.

From the **Learning RxJava Book** by *Thomas Nield*

> If you pass 0 to `autoConnect()` for the `numberOfSubscribers` argument,
> it will start firing immediately and not wait for any Observers. This
> can be handy to start firing emissions immediately without waiting for
> any Observers.